# Does a weighted sequence derived from a sequence matching the Siegel lemma BV bound behave as an uniformly random sequence?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-approximation, probabilistic-number-theory, discrepancy-theory

Pick integers $r_1',\dots,r_t'$ that achieve the Bombieri Vaaler bound for the Siegel lemma and find an $m$ (it exists by Dirichlet Pigeonhole) such that given prime $T$ gets $m(r_1',\dots,r_t')\equiv(r_1,\dots,r_t)\bmod T$ where vector $(r_1,\dots,r_t)$ considered over integers is in box $[-T^{t/(t+1)},T^{t/(t+1)}]^t$. Consider the linear form
$$L(x_1,\dots,x_t)=r_1x_1+\dots+r_tx_t$$ where $-T^{1/(t+1)}<x_1,\dots,x_t<T^{1/(t+1)}$ holds. There are $(2T^{1/(t+1)}+1)^t$ possible choices for $x_1,\dots,x_t$.

The Bombieri-Vaaler bound need not be tight for $(r_1,\dots,r_t)$. So choice of $x_1,\dots,x_t$ need not produce a distinct integer with the linear form.

However we know with the choice of $x_i$ we have $|L(x_1,\dots,x_t)|<tT$. My question is the following:

> 1. With the $(2T^{1/(t+1)}+1)^t$ possible choices of $x_1,\dots,x_t$ for approximately how many choices of $x_1,\dots,x_t$ can we expect $|L(x_1,\dots,x_t)|<T/2$ to hold?
> 2. If we have a random choice of $t$ integers $y_1,\dots,y_t$ uniformly taken from $[-T,T]$ then is the probability of $|y_1+\dots+y_t|<T$ same as above probability and if so what is the convergence rate and if not how far are we away?